# Youtube link in email does not open from iOS mail

Tags: iphone, ios, email, hyperlink, youtube

Just using a link to a youtube video in an e-blast, works fine in any email client, but iOS won't open video. It opens youtube app and says 'can't open video' simple as that.

Anyone with experience in this?
I'm assuming you can't do any if/then being that you'll screw up some other email client.

Comment: when you say any email client, is it any client on iOS or non iOS client? if you can play that video through iOS safari, then your click through action should play the video on iOS

Answer (score 0):

If the video is disabled for playback on mobile devices (on the youtube video settings), this would happen.